# Playing multiple timeline animation in order

Tags: java, animation, timeline

I'm trying to play search through a list, and if that list contains `key` word, it will play that animation.

If the myList contains`{"Cloudy","Cloudy,"Cloudy","Clear"}`
it should play cloudyT animation and loop 3 times and then clearT animation. But 
that is not the cast. I noticed it execute all 4 animations at the same time, causing only one animation to show up. My setCycleCount is the same for all of them.

I also noticed the print statement will print all at once compared print all at once before the animation is finished, meaning that it's not going in waiting for the animation to finishes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < time.length;i++) {  
    if (myList.get(i).equals("Cloudy")) {
        System.out.println("Cloudy found");
        cloudyGrp.setVisible(true); //Group
        cloudyT.setRate(.5); //Timeline
        cloudyT.play();
        cloudyT.setOnFinished(event -> {
            cloudyGrp.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Cloudy animation done");
        });
    }
    if (myList.get(i).equals("Clear")) {
        clearGrp.setVisible(true); //Group
        clearT.setRate(.5); 
        clearT.play(); //Timeline
        clearT.setOnFinished(event -> {
            clearGrp.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("Clear animation done");
        });
    }
    //other if statement with same layout
```

How would I separate them so they play individually one after the other?

I thought of using `Threads` and using priority but not sure how to implement it. Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for `else if`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh sadly `else if` still give the same error

Comment: My bad, I misread the code. It seems you need to make use of the call back system `setOnFinished`, as the loop iterate faster than the animation can play. Instead of a loop, maybe you could recursively handle this. I'll check it out in about 10 minutes, about to head home.

Comment: If my answer seems too complex, let me know and I'll simplify.

Comment: @VinceEmigh thank you for such a detailed explanation, I will try it in a few hours after class

Comment: @VinceEmigh Hi, I'm not sure what animations is referring to in `AnimationWrapper anim = animations.get(requestedAnim); ` and `        anim.play(() -> play(items, index + 1));` is giving me the error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface".

Comment: @VinceEmigh  `AnimationWrapper anim = animations.get(requestedAnim)` oh I think it should be animation instead of animations, even then it should give me an error to cast it `animation` which display a bunch of possible choices that I'm unsure of (array/list/maps)...

Comment: Did you declare the `Map`? It should be `animations` - that's the identifier for the map. Also, `Runnable` is a functional interface - could you edit into your post your `AnimationWrapper#play`?

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

Your loop iterates faster than the animation can play.

Instead of a loop, use recursion, making use of `setOnFinished` to trigger the next animation in the array.

---

## Solution

**Introduce a new type**

When an animation starts, the group should be visible. When the animation stops, the group should be hidden.

The new type would group animations with their displayable group:

```
class AnimationWrapper {
    private Animation animation;
    private Group group;

    public AnimationWrapper(Animation animation, Group group) {
        this.animation = animation;
        this.group = group;
    }
}
```

This new type would handle the playing of animations, as well as hiding/showing of groups, via some `play` method.

The `AnimationWrapper#play` method would accept a callback function for when the animation finishes.

```
class AnimationWrapper {
    // ...

    public void play(Runnable onFinished) {
        group.setVisible(true);
        animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
            group.setVisible(false);
            onFinished.run();
        });

        animation.setRate(.5);
        animation.play();
    }
}
```

**Map the `String` values to their respected `AnimationWrapper`**

The end goal is to introduce a simple interface: "*Play animations based on the values in this `String` array.*"

The class which originally had the loop would introduce a `Map` field:

```
Map<String, AnimationWrapper> animations = new HashMap<>();

// populate somewhere
animations.put("Cloudy", new AnimationWrapper(cloudyT, cloudyGroup);
```

When processing the `String[]` of requests, the `Map` will allow you to easily grab the animation.

**Use recursion**

The goal is to perform:

```
play > onFinished > play > onFinished > ...`
```

This pattern should continue until you've exhausted all `String` values in the array of requests.

In the class with the `Map`, we would declare a `play(String[])` which will handle playing the animations requested from the array.

```
void play(String[] items) {
    play(items, 0);
}

void play(String[] items, int index) {
     // TODO
}
```

Introducing an overload will allow us to keep track of the index across method calls.

In the overloaded method, you'd first check if `index >= items.length`. If index exceeds the array's length, return/exit.

```
void play(String[] items, int index) {
    if(index >= items.length)
        return;
}
```

If the index does not exceed, we'd use it to grab the requested animation, and use the request to access the animation wrapper from the `Map`:

```
void play(String[] items, int index) {
    if(index >= items.length)
        return;

    String requestedAnim = items[index];
    AnimationWrapper anim = animations.get(requestedAnim);
}
```

Once you have the animation, play it. When it finishes, call `play` using the next index.

```
void play(String[] items, int index) {
    if(index >= items.length)
        return;

    String requestedAnim = items[index];
    AnimationWrapper anim = animations.get(requestedAnim);
    anim.play(() -> play(items, index + 1));
}
```

Where you originally had your loop, you would now call:

```
String[] requests = { "Cloudy", "Cloudy", "Cloudy", "Clear" };
play(requests);
```